# useState grava dois arrays, um vazio e um com os dados que eu quero, como faço para pega-los?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou usando uma função get files que pega os files na api e executando no useEffect, quando au atribuo o retorno da função ao setSlideCategory e dou um console log ele retorna isso:

[console.log()slideCategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cIFJ.png)

um array vazio e um com as informações que preciso, como posso resolver ess problema?
Aqui está meu código:

```
var [slideCategory, setSlideCategory] = useState([])

async function getFiles() { const load = new LoadFile()

await load.loadFiles()
.then((res) => { 
  
  setSlideCategory([res])
  
  
 })
.catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
};

useEffect(() => { getFiles()

}, []);


console.log(slideCategory)
```

aqui esta o component que estou usando, ele recebe um data que seria as imagens vindo de uma api, dps chamo esse component slideCategory na home e passo com o useState

```
function SlideCategory({ data, slidesToShow, title }) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState();
  const [slide, setSlide] = useState(6);

  //pega largura da tela
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      // console.log("resized to: ", window.innerWidth);
      if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
        setSlide(1);
      } else if (window.innerWidth > 700 && window.innerWidth < 800) {
        setSlide(3);
      } else if (window.innerWidth > 801 && window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        setSlide(5);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  });

  const fadeProperties = {
    /*  duration: 3000, */
    canSwipe: false,
    slidesToShow: slide,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    indicators: true,
  };

  return (
    <div className="fade-effect-home">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="slide-container-category">
        <Slide {...fadeProperties}>
          {data.map((inf) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="each-fade-category" >
                  <div >
                    <img src={'https://w3i.sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com/psf/imgs/1661432957079.jpeg'}
                    alt="Alternative text" id="fade-category-slide" 
                    onClick={() => setModal(1)} />
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="detalhes-curso"
                    style={modal === 1 ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}
                  >
                    <h2>{'teste'}</h2>
                    <img src={stars} alt="stars" id="stars-modal-description" />
                    <p>{'description'}</p>
                    <div className="icon-perfil-professor">
                      <RiAccountCircleLine size={35} />
                      <h4>{'professor quase nada'}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <button>saiba mais</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </Slide>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

react
react-hooks

Comment: Pelo que mostra (não está muito claro), são dois momentos diferentes: primeiro é logada a array vazia, depois ela preenchida depois que os dados forem obtidos.

Comment: é exatamente essa a minha dúvida, eu dou apenas um console.log apos atribuir o valor da promisse e imprime isso no console, dois arrays, um vazio e um com os dados, minha duvida é como faço pra resolver? o que mais posso acrescentar como informação para trazer clareza?

Comment: Está tudo dentro de getFiles. E getFiles é chamada no useEffect. E useEffect é chamado no início e toda vez que o estado muda. Por isso os múltiplos logs. Me parece que é iso, mesmo com esse código incompleto.

Comment: mesmo com a função fora do useEffect ele da o log desse jeito, e com arrays diferentes, minha duvida seria como atualizer o useState da variavel na primeira vez que renderizar?

Answer (score -2):

O primeiro array vazio está sendo mostrado quando seu componente é montado em tela. O outro array é quando os dados são capturados pelo get

Pra atualizar o state só uma vez, você pode montar o componente em tela somente depois que fizer a requisição get. Tem várias formas de ajustar isso, mas não necessariamente isso é um erro. É só uma mudança de estado do componente na renderização. Dependendo de como você estiver montando seu componente e se estiver usando Next.js, você consegue contornar isso fácil.

Comment: estou usando o react, e não estou conseguindo contaornar isso, pode me dar algum exemplo?

Comment: {data?.map((inf) => { ...

Comment: tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou..

Comment: ele ainda renderiza as duas vezes, to agarrado nesse problema a dois dias e não consigo resolver.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar a interrogação na interação com seu array.

EX:

```
array = []; // Primeira renderização.

array = [{ 'field1': 'campo 1' }]; // Segunda renderização.

array?.[0]?.field1;

// Resultado: campo1
```

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo baseado no meu código do component?